Symfony API-Platform ApiProperty attribute not working for json format
Strange Api-platform activity. It looks like ApiProperty Attribute doesn't work with json format. Why? And how to make ApiProperty to work on json too.
I have simple ApiResource example
#[ApiResource()]
class UserApi
{
    public ?int $id = null;

    public ?string $firstName = null;

    #[ApiProperty(readable: false)]
    public ?string $doNotShow = null;

}

If i request jsonld format http://localhost/api/users/1.jsonld, i get:
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/User",
  "@id": "/api/users/1",
  "@type": "User",
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "john",
}

If i request json format http://localhost/api/users/1.json, i get:
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "john",
  "doNotShow": "secret",
}

PHP 8.2, Symfony 7, "api-platform/core": "3.3.2",
config file: api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: [ 
           '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity',
        ]
    formats:
        json: [ 'application/json' ]
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']

